# Not able to connect Laravel app to database which is hosted on Azzure over ssl

Tags: php, laravel

I am struggling in connecting  Laravel app with MYSQL database. I can connect to database over MySQL Workbench and also with PDO connection custom string but with Laravel I cannot. Not sure what is wrong.

Custom connection string:  It works file is inside laravel app. I put this just for checking

```
$conn = mysqli_init();
mysqli_ssl_set($conn,NULL,NULL, "BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem", NULL, NULL) ; 
mysqli_real_connect($conn, 'sever.host', 'server-username', 'server-password', 'database', 3306, MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL);
if (mysqli_connect_errno($conn)) {
die('Failed to connect to MySQL: '.mysqli_connect_error());
}
else{
    echo "Connected";
}
```

Then I added in .env file following, beside defining username password host and db name. 
BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem file is on same path as .env file

```
MYSQL_SSL_KEY=BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem
MYSQL_SSL_CERT=BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem
MYSQL_SSL_CA=BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem
MYSQL_SSL_CIPHER=BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem

MYSQL_SSL=true
```

In config/database.php looks like this

```
 'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => (env('MYSQL_SSL')) ? [
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY    => env('MYSQL_SSL_KEY'),  // /path/to/key.pem
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT   => env('MYSQL_SSL_CERT'), // /path/to/cert.pem
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA     => env('MYSQL_SSL_CA'),   // /path/to/ca.pem
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CIPHER => env('MYSQL_SSL_CIPHER')
        ] : [],
```

Not sure what is wrong, any idea?

I get these errors:

"error":"SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
[{"file":"D:\home\site\wwwroot\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php","line":624,"function":"runQueryCallback","class":"Illuminate\Database\Connection","type":"->","args":["select * from `backend_token` limit 1",[],{}]},

Comment: Well, what happens? Do you get an error?

Comment: @ceejayoz I updated the question with errors.

Comment: It helps to mention things like which version of Laravel are you using.

What was in the original `config/database.php` file?

Answer (score 0):

It helps to know which version of Laravel you are on to be absolutely sure, but on Laravel 8 my database config has:

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],
```

Don't change your database.php config but in your .env add `MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA=/path/to/BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem`

FYI sometimes if you are using private IP addresses then edit your hosts file

`10.10.10.10   hostname.domain.com`

Where of course the ip number matches the ip of the host.

If that doesn't work, add the cipher line from you config `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CIPHER => env('MYSQL_SSL_CIPHER'),`